# Always returning 500 error

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
console.log('Yes1');
if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
  console.log('Yes2');
  return res.status(401).json(JSON.stringify({
      error: 'Username or Password are not set'
  }));

}else{
 console.log('Yes3');
 return res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify({
      data: 'Okay'
  }));
}


//error handler
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify({
        error: err
    }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

From the front end I am sending a username and password. I am expecting to either be receiving errors 200 or 401. For some reason though I receiving error 500 which is the default error handler. I am not sure how it is coming here. On my server console Yes1 and Yes2 are being printed so why am I not getting error 401?

Comment: @bejado Ahhh I didn't know that. My understanding was this only gets called if next(err) is passed in the router. Removing it fixes the problem. I will have so more complex logic where I will need a 'default' error handler in each router, is there a way to do this then for each router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you have more code or not, but you need to install your router with `app.use('/', router)`.

You also need to install the [`body-parser` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) to be able to parse `req.body`.

Your whole application should look something like this:

```
// router.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Yes1');
  console.log(req.body);
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    console.log('Yes2');
    return res.status(401).json(JSON.stringify({
        error: 'Username or Password are not set'
    }));

  }else{
   console.log('Yes3');
   return res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify({
        data: 'Okay'
    }));
  }
});

//error handler
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify({
        error: err
    }));
});

module.exports = router;

// server.js

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var customRouter = require('./router.js');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use('/', customRouter);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
});
```

See [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) and [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your middleware handler is firing, because 401 is an error, and you are resetting the status to 500.